# Launch the notification bar if a user is using Adblock Pro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen the code before somewhere else but I can't find it. I would like to find a way of notifying users via the Notification bar to add an exception for a website.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20505898/1357033 - Good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the code off-hand but the basic strategy to do this is to attempt to execute code that ad-block pro normally blocks and then check if it ran successfully or not. If not, you can display a notification to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this...

```
var image = new Image();

image.onerror = function() {
   alert('C\'mon, the ads pay for this site :(');
}

image.src = 'http://example.com/known-url-adblock-blocks';
```

*..or...*

- [How To Detect AdBlock Plus](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/07/how-to-detect-adblock-plus-and-display.html)
- [How To Detect AdBlock Plus](http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/how-to-detect-adblock-plus/)
- [Detect Adblock](http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/865/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about launching a notification bar, but I think the method that [this site](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=1872) uses would work... basically, they add a background image behind the ad that shows through when the ad is blocked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could throw a javascript alert up based on any of the methods found on Stackoverflow already:

- [Block all content on a web page for people using an Adblock-type browser add-on/extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001054/block-all-content-on-a-web-page-for-people-using-an-adblock-type-browser-add-on-e)
- [Detecting AdBlocking software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185067/detecting-adblocking-software)
- [Detect adblock and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840368/detect-adblock-and-javascript)
- [How to detect Adblock on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-in-my-website)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way of doing this really simply is checking your ad containers height. You can then detect in almost one line of jQuery!

```
function checkAds()
{
  if($(".ad-container").height()=="0")
  {
    // Show notification here!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My easiest solution with jquery is:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Scripts/custom/advertisement.js", // this is just an empty js file
        dataType: "script",
        success: function () {
          // user doesn't use adblock
        }
    })
    .fail(function () {
       // user uses adblock
    });
```

advertisement.js just contains nothing.